# GWT: get locale information from server side?

Tags: java, spring, gwt, spring-aop

I use GWT along with Spring/Hibernate/AOP. I use an Aspect to send notification emails.
In one of my Aspect, I want to get the current locale from GWT,so that I can send the localized email to the user.
Is there a way to access GWT Locale data from the client side?

Thanks

Comment: You subject says "from server side", your text says "from client side"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html

has info about Locales in GWT.

I have two approaches:

1) session-less server: the method in the server that sends the email receives the locale from the client.

Let's say the interface has a method:

```
doStuffAndSendMails(MyObjectData myObj);
```

My proposal is to convert it to

```
doStuffAndSendMails(MyObjectData myObj, String localeStr);
```

and call it from the GWT client in this way:

```
doStuffAndSendMails(myObj, LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getAsString());
```

2) session-aware server: I don't know if GWT allows using session... and... I prefer not to use it... but if you have to, you can send to the server the locale of the client and store it in the session...

Answer (score 0):

You can have the locale for every **rpc method call** without adding a locale parameter to your methods.

1. add following to the web.xml:

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.rpc</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. and MyServlet class will be like this:

   ```
   public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
      @Override
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           ...
           ...
           Locale userPreferredLocale = request.getLocale();
           ...
           ...

       }
   }
   ```