# Determining user locale on server side in GWT app

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I have implemented i18n on a GWT application to internationalize labels, buttons etc. Is there a way to determine the user locale on the server side of a GWT application. I have found a library called gwt_i18n_server_1.0.jar which I suspect allows me to do this but the documentation is a little thin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about GWT particularly, but if you can access request Object then you can retrieve like

```
Locale userPreferredLocale = request.getLocale();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocaleInfo.html).

EDIT:

I'm sorry, didn't see the

> user locale on the server side

What you could do is send the information from above to the server.

Or have a look at: [GWT: get locale information from server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956299/gwt-get-locale-information-from-server-side)

Comment: Tried using this, but get the following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.gwt.i18n.client.LocaleInfo    I assumed it was because this was a CLIENT ONLY class?

Comment: I updated my answer. I skipped the 'on the server side' part of your question. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can determine the Locale on the client side, you could stuff it into a cookie, then it should be made available to the server on all subsequent requests?  The downside to that would be that you couldn't server a different "first" page depending on locale - you'd have your first page do the detection, then request the content asyncronously.